# Connection refused when trying to access SOLR instance running in boot2docker on windows

Tags: solr, docker, boot2docker

I pulled [this](https://github.com/makuk66/docker-solr) SOLR docker image and then followed the instructions to run it.

```
docker run -d -p 8983:8983 -t makuk66/docker-solr
```

Typing in `docker ps` yielded

```
1197d246f0e3        makuk66/docker-solr:latest   "/bin/bash -c '/opt/   50 minutes ago      Up 50 minutes       0.0.0.0:8983->8983/tcp             suspicious_sinoussi
```

So I know it's running.

In order to connect to it I know I can't use localhost because it's running on the virtual machine. So I used `ipconfig` which yielded:

```
Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::cd9a:3e57:6d13:de3b%19
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network #2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::1d62:c4b5:9436:518e%27
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.59.3
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

However when trying to connect to either of these IPs: `192.168.56.1` or `192.168.59.3` with and without the port `:8983` specified I get

> Google Chrome's connection attempt to 192.168.59.3 was rejected. The website may be down, or your network may not be properly configured.

How can I properly connect to the SOLR process running on docker?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was over complicating the debugging.
When Boot2Docker first starts up it prints the message:

> IP address of docker VM:
>   192.168.59.103

This IP allows you to access the SOLR instance.

The command:

```
boot2docker ip
```

Also lets you know what this IP is.